# how to find USB devices in Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, linux, unix, cygwin

In Cygwin on Windows 7, in which directory would you find your iPod or in my case, my SAMSUNG GT-N8103? I didn't see anything in `dev` that hints where to find it.

Comment: Is it mapped to a drive letter in Windows? Try checking inside `/cygdrive/`

Comment: check this too: http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html

Answer (score 6):

All storage devices which get mounted with Windows drive letters will appear beneath `/cygdrive/`.  For example, `C:\Windows\` is `/cygdrive/c/Windows/` and `I:\My Music\` is `/cygdrive/i/My\ Music/`

Comment: where is your iPod or Android device? path?

Answer (score 5):

you can not find if your phone is connected with MTP connection as cygwin is not a full operating system, does not provide (kernel-mode) drivers for hardware and will not behave like a full UNIX OS will in all cases, as per [USB device not recognized in cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/406788/usb-device-not-recognized-in-cygwin) but if your phone is connected as a mass storage device then you can mount it in Cygwin as

```
/cygdrive/I(or any letter)/
```